# How do I start my page with routing and/or querystring data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, query-string, asp.net-mvc-routing

When my page first loads, the URL looks like this: http://localhost:1245/. However, I'd like it to look like this: http://localhost:1245/Home/Index/2/2012?Events=Show (/2/2012?Events=Show is the important part). How do I get my page to load with that second URL from the very beginning?

Comment: You want it to start that way for debugging, or you want anyone who would visit the website to goto that url?

Comment: No debug, for production. I want regular users to go to that URL.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're asking. I want them to go to an URL with that URL format, not necessarily those values. The calendar will default today's month and year.

Comment: Is it necessary for the end user to see the full path and the full query string?

Comment: It would be nice, but I'll take an alternative if you have one.

Comment: User can type any url when they want to come to your website. The better thing is you have to do a redirection if they come from a different URL.

Comment: @Mark - It's an intranet site that's a calendar. So it's okay if the user does that. Otherwise, I agree with your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is add a new route prior to the default MVC route so it looks something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "NewDefault", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{month}/{year}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Events", 
        action = "Shows", 
        month = DateTime.Now.Month,
        year = DateTime.Now.Year } // Parameter defaults
  );

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```

The default URL (interally, not visible to the user) would be `/Events/Shows/4/2012` (if the date is `4/19/2012`). The default controller would be `EventsController` and the default action would be `EventsController.Shows`.

```
public EventsController
{
  public ActionResult Shows(int month, int year)
  {
    someModel model = new someModel();
    someModel.month = month;
    someModel.year = year;
    this.View(someModel);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh. I see. What about the querystring portion?

Comment: I converted your querystring into controller/action.

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
  routes.MapRoute("MyRouteName", 
    "Home/Index/2/2012", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

To your routings.

Change the Index action of HomeController to have the following signature:

```
public ActionResult Index(string Events)....
```

Comment: Is there anyway /2/2012 can be not hardcoded but determined at the controller?

Comment: You don't get to your controller unless there is a route that sends you there, unless the url follows the standard controller\action\id convention.